# A string is separated by different delimeter . I have to reverse each wordof string with position of delimeter to be same

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Problem statement :

```
var str = "my,name!is? aditya"
```

Output should be :

```
 ym,eman!si? aytida
```

=> reverse each word separated by any delimeter with position of delimeter remains same after reversal.

What I tried:

```
str=str.split('').reverse().join('')
```

But it is printing whole string in reverse direction . How to achieve the desired result ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reverse each *word*, not the whole string. One option would be to use `.replace` - match word characters, and use a callback that reverses each word:

```js
var str = "my,name!is? aditya"
console.log(
  str.replace(/\w+/g, word => [...word].reverse().join(''))
);
```